# Prevent hidden property of aut-generated class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

## Situation

I have several classes auto-generated from a database, that share some common properties, among which the property *Name*. I need a variable *CurrentItem* that can hold any instance of these classes, regardless of its type, so I can access their common properties.

To achieve that, I created a base class `DBItem` that implements only the common properties, and I made all my (partial) classes inherit from it.

## Problem

I get the message `'MyClass.Name hides inherited member DBItem.Name. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.` The fix seems easy, except my classes are auto-generated since they are derived from my database. Therefore I can't apply the recommanded solution.

This might be considered as a simple warning, and be ignored. I think however that it's causing some issues later in my program. In particular, when a DBItem is created, it seems to have two different *Name* properties. One called *Name* which is properly filled, and one called *Name (Entity.DBItem)*, which is `null`. And if I try to access the *Name* property with `CurrentItem.Name`, the result is null.

How can I solve this problem so that I can access the *Name* property from a `DBItem` ?

## Edit

Additionnal informations: 
Here is an example of an auto-generated class:

```
namespace LTG_Entity
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Environment
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Environment()
        {
            this.TemplateEnvironments = new HashSet<TemplateEnvironment>();
            this.Packages = new HashSet<Package>();
            this.Metas = new HashSet<Meta>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TemplateEnvironment> TemplateEnvironments { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Package> Packages { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Meta> Metas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the base very simple class DBItem:

```
namespace LTG_Entity
{
    public class DBItem
    {
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use edmx and VisualStudio 2017.

Comment: You have to setup inheritance in your model(-mapping). Post sample classes, the toolset (edbmx?) used and the version of .NET and EF.

Comment: This begs for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: best idea: drop edmx and start using code-first. There is a one-time tool to create POCOs from a database.

Comment: And with POCOs or edmx, you have to configure the inheritance. It won't work all by itself. Can't help you with edmx, im have started to forget it.